# Array of objects from two arrays

Tags: php

If i have the following array

```
$arr = [4,7,8];
$var = 3
```

and need the following result using PHP functions and operators or most efficient way for large arrays.

```
$result = [
 [3,4],
 [3,7],
 [3,8]
]
```

Comment: why the Yii2 tag? between you can use `array_walk` which **Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array**  but talking about performance with large arrays, nothing beats a `foreach` loop.

Comment: I just updated the question with my proposal and deleted Yii2 tag.

Comment: just use foreach

Comment: ^ This is the most efficient way.

Comment: What do you mean with "This" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way is the following

```
$col1 = array_pad($vals,sizeof($arr),$var); // [3,3,3]
$result = array_map(null,$col1,$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php

$arr = [4, 7, 8];
$var = 3;

$result = array_map(
    function ($itm) use ($var) {
        return [$var, $itm];
    },
    $arr
);
```

**UPDATE:** I've checked it. So my variant is **slower** in two time than the variant with foreach

Answer (score 0):

Idk about performance, but use basic maybe lightweight.

```
$arr = [4,7,8];
$var = 3;

$result = [];

// 
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++)
{
  $result[$i] = [$var, $arr[$i]];
}
```

Comment: You are counting $arr on each iteration.  Consider: `for($i = 0, $c = sizeof($arr); $i < $c; $i++)` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = [4,7,8];
$var = 3;

foreach($arr as $v)
    $out[]=[$var, $v];

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
0 => 
array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 4,
),
1 => 
array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 7,
),
2 => 
array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 8,
),
)
```

Comment: Would a reference be of any advantage here?  `$out[]=[&$var, $v];`